# laravel redirection with parameter not working as intended?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am using resource routes for routing in laravel 5. I used the code, like the following:

```
return Redirect::route('tquoted-eqs.create',['tqid'=>$tqid]);
```

I want pass value suppose `$tid=6` on named route `tquoted-eqs.create` using `GET` method.The URL now should look like

`http://localhost/project/tquoted-eqs/create?tqid=16`

but instead shows

`http://localhost/medisup/tquoted-eqs/create?tqid%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=16`

on address bar after redirection.I also tried to use

`redirect()->route('tquoted-eqs.create',['tqid'=>$tqid])`

but this also produced same awkward URL.What may be the problem here?

Comment: try redirect(tquoted-eqs/create,['tqid'=>$tqid])

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
return Redirect::to(URL::to('tquoted-eqs.create', ['tqid'=>$tqid]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in the `route()` method is reserved for route parameters: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L153

Try just tacking the query string on the end manually, i.e.

```
return redirect(route('tquoted-eqs.create').'?tqid='.$tqid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
return Redirect::route('tquoted-eqs.create', [$tqid]);
```

Removed the key `['tqid' =>` from the parameters array. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**In March 2017, this seems to be the answer using Laravel 5.4:**

```
Route::get('/yourOldPath', function () {
    return redirect()->route('someOtherRouteName', \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all());//Input::all() is like $_GET
});
```